# How to check if Bugsense is running in my Android application

Tags: android, bugsense

BugSense work perfect on my application but i want to make sure if it is running?
I cant find any why to do this?

I imagine something like this:

```
if (BugSenseHandler == null) {
   BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "API KEY");
}
```

Thanks..

Comment: First of all, `BugSenseHandler` is a class, so it will never be null.  That code won't even compile.  Second, BugSense doesn't "run" in the sense you seem to be thinking.  It registers itself as the VM's default exception handler and gets called if an exception propagates out of the app.  There doesn't seem to be a method to test whether `initAndStartSession(...)` has been called, but there doesn't seem to be any harm in calling it more than once.

Comment: Okay. So you have to have your finger cross and hope BugSense is running, if you don't want to call it each 1 min or somthing.

Comment: Just register it in your main activity's `onCreate()`, or in your application's `onCreate()` if you've extended Application.  Nothing else is going to change the default exception handler unless you tell it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Kostas, the Android developer of BugSense.

If you use the initAndStartSession method, BugSense will be running until the application get's out of the stack. More info on tasks and back stack [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

That's why we recommend to place the initAndStartSession method at the first (starting) activity of your application.

There is absolutely no problem in using the initAndStartSession method in every onCreate method of your activities, you can also put it in every onResume too, we've already taken care of this possibility. If you want to be 100% sure that BugSense is running, you can go this way.